# 4 Relay Shield rebooting Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am using a four relay shield to power solenoids, however every time a solenoid is used the Arduino reboots immediately.

We have done this for two different projects with the same type of shield and both cause the same problem.

I am having some trouble figuring out what is causing the system reboot. Any ideas?

The shield is the Catalex relay Shield.

Comment: Please edit your post to include what is powering the Arduino and your sketch.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like driving a relay coil is causing the voltage to drop.  After the voltage recovers, the Arduino reboots like it was just turned on.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you disconnect the solenoids?  Does the same behavior happen? These are relays, so the circuit on the relay side should be isolated.

Are you powering the Arduino from a power supply, or the USB port?

Oddly, if you look up the data sheet for the HLS8L-DC5V-S-C:

http://www.dipmicro.com/?datasheet=HLS8L.pdf

it says a 5V relay (L type) should have a coil resistance of 70 Ohms , for 0.35 W, so you should need 70 mA to drive it; I think there is a small transistor that drives *that* from the pins, but you still need the 70 mA from somewhere to close each relay.

Which version of the board do you have?

http://seeedstudio.com/wiki/Relay_Shield

My search on the Catalex Relay Shield pointed to the Seeedstudio version, but it could be that your board needs to be externally powered.